# Отправка файла ajax'ом ни в какую не работает

Tags: javascript, ajax

Код ниже не работает, в консоли ошибка:

> jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"...

Что не так? `datatype` не обязательный же параметр?

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="userFile" id="file" value="Выбрать файл"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="sendFile();" value="test"/>
</form>
<div id="div_qwe"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function sendFile() {
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "post",
    data: new FormData($('#file').parents('form:first')[0]),
    success: function(qwe){
        $("#div_qwe").append(qwe);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(exception);
    }
});
}
```

**PHP**

```
if($_FILES['userFile']['size']>0) {
    echo 'Файл принят!';
}
```

А если все тоже самое но

```
data: 'file_xlsx = ' + $('#file').val(),
```

Выдает ошибку php файл следующего содержания:

> Notice: Undefined index: file_xlsx in ajax.php on line 3

Comment: Посмотри здесь, решение тут уже находили http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/381936/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-ajax-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-file

Comment: @DimaKrivenko указанный вами метод приемлем ко всем типам файлов? У меня почему то не работает с xlsx ошибку выдает как в вопросе самая первая