# Передать файл с содержими формы ajax

Tags: javascript

Есть форма с возможностью передать файл.
Как передать форму я понимаю, но как прикрепить еще и файл?

Я написал таким образом, но это не работает:

```
var files;
$('fetch-file-input').change(function() {
    files = this.files;
});
// при нажатии на кпопку
$(function() {
    var url = defaultPath + "reports/fetch/294";
    $('#modal_form_fetch').on('submit', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation(); 
        event.preventDefault(); 

        var data = new FormData();
        $.each(files, function(key, value) {
            data.append(key, value);
        });

        var $that = $(this), fData = $that.serialize(); // сериализируем данные, я прочел про этот метод и понял что с помощью его можно получить строку, пригодную для передачи через URL.
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type : 'POST',
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            data : {
                form_data : fData
            },
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(json) {
                // В случае успешного завершения запроса...
                if (json) {
                    $that.replaceWith(json);
                    output.append('<p>Запрос завершен!</p>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: "не работает" - ??

Comment: как соотносятся `var data` и `var fData`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/381954/16224

Comment: сначала я считываю данные из файла и помещаю их в data, затем добавляю их в fData = $that.serialize();

Comment: зачем Вам переменная `data`, если Вы ее после заполнения нигде не используете?

Comment: Игорь, у меня в этом и проблема, я не догоняю, как объединить данные с формы вместе с файлом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема кроется в этой строке: `var fData = $that.serialize();`

Не помню уже где вычитал, но serialize() не работает с multipart/form-data и конкретно файлами.

Поэтому нужно использовать `var fData = new FormData($that);`

Ну и не забыть в форме указать `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: спасибо, это решило проблему