# Передача файла в форме AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть два отчета.
В первом форма содержит текстовые значения.
Во втором форма содержит текстовые значения и оператор прикрепляет файл.

Код формы:

```
<form action="<%=Constants.LINK_INTERNAL_PREFIX %>reports/fetch/<%=entry.get("id") %>" method="POST"
                    class="form-inline-report col-md-8" id="fetch-report" 
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Код для вставки файла:

```
<% if (entry.get("use_file").equals("true")) { %>
            <input id="fetch-file-input" class="fileinput" name="fetch-file-input" type="file" />
            <div id="errorBlock" class="help-block"></div>
```

...

```
<input value="Send" type="submit">
        </form>
```

Код JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#fetch-report").submit(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : $(this).attr('action'),
            data : $('#fetch-report').serialize(),
            success : function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

При отправке отчета 1 все отрабатывает.
При отправке отчета 2 ошибка от сервера:

> ERROR UPLOADING FILE
>   01/12/2018 18:23:21 [EROR] ?                     javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Как прикрутить в JS возможность отправки файла?
Мне нужен AJAX?

Comment: Вам ведь уже ответили на такой же вопрос: [Передать файл с содержими формы ajax](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769429/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробовали использовать `FormData`?

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('input_name', $('#input_name').val());
formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
jQuery.ajax({
     url: '/upload',
     data: formData,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
     }
});
```

Comment: var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form').get(0)); вот так отработало

Comment: ну я написал последовательное добавление инпутов)

Comment: да мне еще предстоит все это выучить))