# Загрузка фотографий в БД

Tags: javascript, php

Есть такая функция, для загрузки фотографий в БД с помощью пхп, как это все переписать на JS, чтобы все происходило без перезагрузки страницы?

```
<form method="post" style = "width:50%; margin-left:200px" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="v-title">Upload your FRONT image photo</div>
                        <div class="profile__drag profile__drag--v">
                            <img id="photo" src="img/icons/v-plus.png" width="100" height="100" name="image">
                            <div class="profile__drag-info">
                            <input type="file" 
                                 onchange="document.getElementById('photo').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" name="file" />
                            <input type="submit" name="uploadf" value="Upload"  / onclick=fff("Upload!")>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</form>                     

<?php
if(isset($_POST['uploadf'])) {
if(empty($_FILES['file']['size']))  die('Вы не выбрали файл');
if($_FILES['file']['size'] > (5 * 1024 * 1024)) die('image size <5mb');
$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$arr = array('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');
if(!in_array($imageinfo['mime'],$arr)) echo ('image format');
 else {

$upload_dir = './img/front/';
$name = $upload_dir.date('YmdHis').basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

$mov = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$name);
  if($mov) {

$name = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($name)));

$mysqli->query("UPDATE Verification SET IMGfront='$name' WHERE id='".$sesion_id."'");
  }

 }
}

?>
```

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/381936/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-ajax-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-file

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб это сделать одним **PHP** не обойтись, используйте [**AJAX**](http://javascript.ru/ajax/intro)

Вот хороший пример, https://wp-kama.ru/id_9026/jquery-ajax-zagruzka-fajlov-na-server.html